# getting spanish response using gather into XML

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, voice, twilio-twiml

With this code Im trying to get the voice response transcribed to text and sent out to a webhook, However im just getting the call details sent at the end of the call, this might help but I need to gather the response of a survey what am I missing?

```
const fromPhoneNumber = '+52xxxxxxx';
const toPhoneNumber = '+52xxxx';
const audioUrl = 'https://twilioaudiohcp.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/tono.mp3';
const VoiceResponse = require('twilio').twiml.VoiceResponse;

const response = new VoiceResponse();
const gather = response.gather({
  input: 'speech',
  language: 'es-MX',
  action: 'https://hook.us1.make.com/8w93jvblq7kel319zvtdkqbqv8mgbwu5/response',
});

gather.say('Please speak your response after the beep.');

const twiml = `<Response><Play>${audioUrl}</Play></Response>`;

client.calls
  .create({
    twiml: twiml,
    from: fromPhoneNumber,
    to: toPhoneNumber,
    record: true,
    language: 'es-MX',
    transcribe: true,
    statusCallback: 'https://hook.us1.make.com/8w93jvblq7kel319zvtdkqbqv8mgbwu5',
    statusCallbackEvent: ['completed'],
    statusCallbackMethod: 'POST'
  })
  .then(call => {
    console.log(call.sid);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error('Failed to make the call:', error);
  });

// Convert the response to XML string
const xmlString = response.toString();

console.log(xmlString);
`
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the [TranscribeCallback](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/record#attributes-transcribe-callback) parameter so you are not being notified when a transcription is complete:

The transcribeCallback attribute is used in conjunction with the transcribe attribute. It allows you to specify a URL to which Twilio will make an asynchronous POST request when the transcription is complete. This is not a request for TwiML and the response will not change call flow, but the request will contain the standard TwiML request parameters as well as transcription specific ones.

If transcribeCallback is specified, then there is no need to specify transcribe=true; it is implied. If you specify transcribe=true without a transcribeCallback, the completed transcription will be stored for you to retrieve later (see the REST API Transcriptions section), but Twilio will not asynchronously notify your application.

Comment: thanks I got it figured out changing the gather request to this

    const response = new VoiceResponse();
    const gather = response.gather({
      input: 'speech',
      language: 'es-MX',
      action: webhookEndpoint,
      speechTimeout: 10, // Set the gathering timeout to 10 seconds
      method: 'POST' // Specify the method for the webhook
    });

    gather.play(audioUrl);
    const twiml = response.toString();